# Regex Matching Square Brackets

Tags: regex, perl

I'm parsing a log file and am stuck on trying to write a regex for the following token

```
sshd[7623]:
```

I can match the sshd string, but when matching the opening square bracket, perl just throws an error about missing the closing square bracket.

If I try matching both at the same time, as below, I don't catch either.

```
$re1='(\\[)(\\d+)(\\])';
$re2='(\\[.*?\\])';
```

But neither have worked. What is a proper way to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This captures the word before the bracket and the number inside the bracket:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

if ('sshd[7623]:' =~ /(\w+)\[(\d+)\]:/) {
    print "word=$1 number=$2\n";
}

__END__

word=sshd number=7623
```

[perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>)
{
   if ( /^(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/ )
   {
      print "Found a $1 line with process ID $2\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
sshd[1234]: Foo
imapd[5678]: Bar
sshd[9012]: Baz
pop3d[3456]: Quux
```