# Perl matching string with mix of alphanumeric,_ and any number of square braces

Tags: regex, perl, matching

How do I match a string with " alphanumeric characters, underscore and any number of open and closed square braces ". 
Example : 
`" CDN_MBIT_hresp_s_reg[0]_MB_hresp_s_reg[1]bbjabs_chiansmokrs[6] "`

I tried `$line=~/[a-zA-Z0-9_/[/]]/;`
This seems doesn't work.

P.S. This question is quite similar to [Regex Matching Square Brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617047/regex-matching-square-brackets/)
but not same
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wrong escape character. It's not `/` but `\ `. Try `$line=~/[a-zA-Z0-9_\[\]]/;`

Answer (score 3):

Wrong slash used for escaping.

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9_\[\]]/
```

Alternatively, you could simply use

```
/[\w\[\]]/
```

Both of those match exactly one character. If you wanted to capture the string, you'd want

```
/([\w\[\]]+)/
```